# Solving a simple recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm learning how to solve some simple recursive sequences.
I'm a bit stuck with the following example
$$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + 3.$$
What substitution would be a good choice here?

Comment: This is an arithmetic sequence $a_n=a_{n-1}+k$. Haven't you learned its explicit solution $a_n=a_0+nk$ ?

Comment: what are you solving for? a general formula? or some sort of limit? Please provide context and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1=a_0+3$

$a_2=a_1+3$

$a_3=a_2+3$

.
.
.

$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+3$

$a_n=a_{n-1}+3$

By adding

$a_n=a_1+3n$

Comment: Did you mean $a_n=a_1+3(n-1)$?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner   thanks

Comment: Or you could start with $a_1=a_0+3$

Answer (score 1):

One basic way to do it is to recurse and look for a pattern:
$$
\begin{split}
a_n &= a_{n-1} + 3 \\
    &= (a_{n-2} + 3) + 3
     = a_{n-2} + 3 \cdot 2 \\
    &= (a_{n-3} + 3) + 3 \cdot 2
     = a_{n-3} + 3 \cdot 3 \\
    &\ldots \\
    &= a_{n-n} + 3 n.
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?

---

A different approach is writing out a couple of terms:
$$
a_0, a_1 = a_0 + 3, a_2 = a_1 + 3 = a_0 + 2 \cdot 3, \ldots
$$
which is just $a_0,a_0+3,a_0+3\cdot 2, \ldots$, which is a simple arithmetic progression

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to read into the expression.

Given relation says every term is 3 more than previous term. Or, difference between consecutive terms is a constant (3).

Which one of the sequences you already familiar with, satisfies our observed property?